# React.memo with typescript in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using React.memo() in a .tsx file(React typescript)

Now I have declared an interface for Props as:

```
interface Props {
  type?: string;
}
```

My component looks like:

```
const Component: React.SFC<Props> = props => {
  /// return something;
};

export default memo(Component);
```

Now since type is an optional prop I intend to use it only sometimes.

If I use my component as `<Component type="something" />` everything is okay.
But if I use it as `<Component />` I get the error -->

> Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.

This seems to be a very absurd error as I have tried this on Code sandbox and everything works fine. Any ideas about what the error could be?

**UPDATE**

If I explicitly add a prop in interface like

```
interface Props {
  type?: string;
  children?: ReactNode;
}
```

then in that case everything works fine. This is supposed to be implicit but acc to the error its taking as

> '{ children: string; }'

Any ideas???

Comment: Have you tried to rename the prop? React.memo uses some prop called type.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/6lmwvxj0vk
But it works in this sandbox.

Comment: Plus I tried renaming. Didnt work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe there is an error in typings. Changing

```js
function memo<P extends object>(
  Component: SFC<P>,
  propsAreEqual?: (
    prevProps: Readonly<PropsWithChildren<P>>,
    nextProps: Readonly<PropsWithChildren<P>>
  ) => boolean
): NamedExoticComponent<P>;
```

to

```js
function memo<P extends object>(
  Component: SFC<P>,
  propsAreEqual?: (
    prevProps: Readonly<PropsWithChildren<P>>,
    nextProps: Readonly<PropsWithChildren<P>>
  ) => boolean
): NamedExoticComponent<PropsWithChildren<P>>;
```

fixes the issue

**UPDATE**

Well, actually it is not a bug. See [discussion](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/33602).

TLTR: You have to specify `children` in component props type.

```js
type MyComponentProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
```

[Read more](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/basic_type_example#useful-react-prop-type-examples)

Comment: `React.SFC` is deprecated. `React.FC` should work fine. Also, you might not need to define `NamedExoticComponent`, nor will you have to extend object if need be. However, you should define your Interface and Types.

Comment: An example of using the ```memo``` function would improve this answer