# Typescript generic class equivalent for React.memo

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, memo

Is there any way to set new generic in React.memo?

For example, for class components, I can use

```
// set generic
class GenericClass<G extends string | number> extends PureComponent {}

// and use like this
<GenericClass<number> />
```

In the below scenario, I want to make type G generic.

```
type G = string;
const MemoComponent = memo<{ value: G; onValueChange: (newValue: G) => void }>(
  ({ value, onValueChange }) => {
    return (
      <select
        onClick={() => {
          // do calculation
          onValueChange(value);
        }}
      >
        Button
      </button>
    );
  }
);
```

I want to know is there any way to set generic in React.memo too? For example, like below

```
const MemoComponent = <G extends string | number | object>React.memo<{value: G}>(({value}) => component)

// and use like this
<MemoComponent<number> />
```

Comment: Can you add more code? Show what you have tried? What is the final thing you expect out of the memoized component?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60386614/how-to-use-props-with-generics-with-react-memo/60389122#60389122

Answer (score 80):

I had the same issue and solved like this.

```js
    interface ISomeComponentWithGenericsProps<T> { value: T; } 

    function SomeComponentWithGenerics<T>(props: ISomeComponentWithGenericsProps<T>) {
      return <span>{props.value}</span>;
    }

    export default React.memo(SomeComponentWithGenerics) as typeof SomeComponentWithGenerics;
```

Comment: This is possible. As `useMemo` and `React.memo` have different use cases and behavior. Tried and worked. Thanks!

Comment: This saved my life. By far the simplest solution I've seen thanks. FU Typescript.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer!

Although you lose the ability to see it is an ExoticComponent, that doesn't really seem to matter as the interface should be the same anyway in actual implementation.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Thank you! Adding `as typeof XXX` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 34):

You can write your own wrapper not to use type assertion(as) :

```
const genericMemo: <T>(component: T) => T = memo

function GenericComponent<Value>({props: PropsWithGeneric<Value>}) {
  return <div />
}

export const GenericMemoComponent = genericMemo(GenericComponent)
```

Comment: Perfect answer, it's helped me thx :)

Comment: This is drastically preferred over the higher-rated answer, as using type assertions is rarely a good idea. Thank you Dmitriy Vergiles.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on [Dmitriy Vergiles'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70890101/807838) answer - to include the `propsAreEqual` equality function:

```js
const genericMemo: <T>(
  component: T,
  propsAreEqual?: (
    prevProps: React.PropsWithChildren<T>,
    nextProps: React.PropsWithChildren<T>
  ) => boolean
) => T = memo;

function GenericComponent<Value>({props: PropsWithGeneric<Value>}) {
  return <div />
}

export const GenericMemoComponent = genericMemo(
  GenericComponent, 
  (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    // Check props
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work :>

```
export type SomeComponentProps<T> = {
...
}
    
// eslint-disable-next-line react-refresh/only-export-components
const SomeComponent = memo(function SomeComponent<T extends string>(props:SomeComponentProps<T>) {
// ...
})

type SomeComponentGeneric = (typeof SomeComponent)["type"];
export default SomeComponent as SomeComponentGeneric;
```

I don't know why I get warning saying that `Fast refresh only works when a file only exports components...` but when I remove `as ...` at `export default ...`, the warning disappear. Maybe eslint need some update :>

> My answer is based on Rafael Fontes

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Turnip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76453035/13325455)'s answer...

`memo` adds `displayName` as a property to the component. We can manually add this to the type:

```
export const genericMemo: <T>(
  component: T,
  propsAreEqual?: (prevProps: React.PropsWithChildren<T>, nextProps: React.PropsWithChildren<T>) => boolean
) => T & { displayName?: string } = memo;
```

Unfortunately, `prevProps` and `nextProps` aren't well-typed and we lose type safety in the equality function.

We can use `React.ComponentProps` to rectify this:

```
export const genericMemo: <T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>>(
  component: T,
  propsAreEqual?: (prevProps: React.ComponentProps<T>, nextProps: React.ComponentProps<T>) => boolean
) => T & { displayName?: string } = memo;
```

In my project, I call this function `typedMemo`, and enforce the usage of it over `memo` with a crude `eslint` rule:

```
'no-restricted-syntax': [
  'error',
  {
    message: 'React\'s `memo` strips types from generic components. Use `typedMemo` instead.',
    selector: 'CallExpression[callee.name="memo"]',
  },
],
```

Whenever `memo` is used, `eslint` complains. I'm not sure how to narrow this rule to only selector for the `memo` function from `react`.