# How to use Props with Generics with React.memo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to convert the following to use `React.memo`:

```
interface Props<TRowData> {
  // props...
}

export function Table<TRowData>({
  propA,
  propB
}: Props<TRowData>) {

}
```

Like so (incorrect):

```
interface Props<TRowData> {
  // props...
}



export const Table = memo<Props<TRowData>>(
({
  propA,
  propB
}) => {

})
```

How can I correct this syntax? Currently it has this error:

```
// Cannot find name 'TRowData'.
export const Table = memo<Props<TRowData>>(
                                ~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I solved it by keeping the memo and non-memo separate and doing some type casting:

```
const TableComponent = <T,>(props: TableComponentProps<T>) => {
 // ...
}

// or
function TableComponent<T>(props: TableComponentProps<T>) {
  // ...
}
```

Then:

```
export const Table = memo(TableComponent) as typeof TableComponent
```

Or:

```
const typedMemo: <T>(c: T) => T = React.memo
export const Table = typedMemo(TableComponent)
```

Answer (score 11):

With current React type declarations, it is not possible to create a generic component out of `React.memo`. A solution without type assertions is to add an additional [`memo`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b481f65c6d72bea2b05ba76b2c003cfff8c9d076/types/react/index.d.ts#L811) function overload to leverage TS 3.4 [higher order function type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions):

```
import React, { memo } from "react"

declare module "react" { // augment React types
  function memo<A, B>(Component: (props: A) => B): (props: A) => B
  // return type is same as ReturnType<ExoticComponent<any>>
}
```

You then will be able to make `Table` component generic. Just make sure to pass a generic function to `memo`:

```
interface Props<T> {
  a: T
}

const TableWrapped = <T extends {}>(props: Props<T>) => <div>{props.a}</div>

const Table = memo(TableWrapped)

const App = () => (
  <>
    <Table a="foo" /> {/* (props: Props<string>) => ... */}
    <Table a={3} /> {/* (props: Props<number>) => ... */}
  </>
)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecRIgRwC+cAZlBCHAERSoa0CwAUGwCZJoA2KD+CBwCuPJHQboYtXGzgVhAOwzAIi-IQgAeAILYAQgD4AFHPlwAwtUiKkimAC44xsFTABnJzoCUcALyGcPpm3k4ubp5wPv6ByFIAomIE9nAAPnCKojxsJGxswPZIUOTo4gAKEVoAKoE4ZihOVTl5rGhq7vBVKABGYgDqUChgYEgc-nDVcEgAHjB2HO64JCauEB5OFWvu1Ya+ARMcwABuhjirHgB0KCRaAPSHJy1tih1wXb3ifhpExu-9g8NRt4nu14DphuNjHtAqZWPItIYzPC-uIUH5aOQIBAZLdarcAFTOc6RTYeLQdKAFADmuxicAuDLg+NuuTh5mqPTEcDROAAzGRcbgCUSIhtKpkQN0irT9gyLkyWWY7ojWMDWEA)

Comment: Why to use `function memo<A, B>(Component: (props: A) => B): (props: A) => ReactElement | null` instead of `function memo<A, B>(Component: (props: A) => B): (props: A) => B`?

Comment: I don't recommend overriding the types of functions from other libraries. It's a slick solution, but it's best to create a `typedMemo` or use `as` instead so the code's portable. This is some serious tech debt otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you need to pass a component as the first parameter of `React.memo`? I couldn't test it, but I feel like this is the thought process:

```
// Overall format:
export const Table = memo(MyComponent, MyFunction)

// With empty arrow function:
export const Table = memo(MyComponent, () => {})

// With your code:
export const Table = memo(MyComponent, ({propA, propB}: Props<TRowData>) => {

})
```

Comment: I believe you're along the right lines, I think it would need wrapping in a HOC style with this approach. I've managed to solve it with some casting but maybe there is a more "correct" solution

Answer (score -2):

Simple, just pass a non-arrow function to `React.memo`:

```js
export const Table = React.memo(function<T>(props: Props<T>) {

})
```

or if you need default export:

```js
export default React.memo(function Table<T>(props: Props<T>) {

})
```

Edit:
You can check that this works with the following code:

```
type MyProps<T> = {someField: T};
const MyComponent = React.memo(function <T>({someField}: MyProps<T>) {
  return <div>{someField}</div>
});

<MyComponent someField={222} />;
<MyComponent someField={'MYSTRING'} />;

const element = React.createElement(MyComponent, {someField: 22});
```

Type of `element` is

```
React.FunctionComponentElement<{someField: number}>
```

Comment: This won't work. React.memo does not pass generics through.

Comment: Updated with an example

Comment: Cannot use the format like `<MyComponent<string> someField={'222'} />`
I don't think this is a expected answer.

Comment: He wanted to set type during the implementation not initiation of the component. So my answers the question being asked